# Try-catch FormatException

Tags: c#, try-catch, formatexception

I'm trying to catch the FormatException when someone tries to enter something else than numerals into int IloscPracownikow but I don't really understand how that should work. I tried doing it with strings but then, that int has to be used in the List which has an int in it.

```
                int IloscPracownikow = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                try
                {
                    object age = IloscPracownikow;
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Podaj liczbe, debilu");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Podaj rok zalozenia firmy.");
                int Rok = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                listaFirm.Add(new Firma(NazwaFirmy, IloscPracownikow, Rok));
```

Comment: The line that throws the exception has to go *inside* the try block, not outside.

Comment: The thing you want to *try* should go within the `try` block. But don't do that, use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't *catch exceptions*, but use [`int.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8): nothing *exceptionable* in the user input (user can put any string and this is expected behivior).

```
  if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int IloscPracownikow)) {
    // User input - Console.ReadLine() - is a valid integer (IloscPracownikow)
    object age = IloscPracownikow;
    ...
  }
  else {
    // User input - Console.ReadLine() - is NOT a valid integer
    Console.WriteLine("Podaj liczbe, debilu");
    ...
  }
```

If you *insist* on catching exceptions, you should put potential exception source (which is `Int32.Parse`) within `try {...}`

```
 try {
   // Possible FormatException throw (if user input is not a valid integer)
   int IloscPracownikow = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

   // and this will never throw FormatException
   object age = IloscPracownikow;

   Console.WriteLine("Podaj rok zalozenia firmy.");

   // Possible FormatException throw
   int Rok = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

   listaFirm.Add(new Firma(NazwaFirmy, IloscPracownikow, Rok));
 }
 catch (FormatException) {
   // either IloscPracownikow or Rok is invalid
   Console.WriteLine("Podaj liczbe, debilu");
 }
```

Comment: This cannot be stated enough in my opinion. Exceptions should be avoided. One might say they should be the (cough) exception. On top of that, you should trap exceptions in the smallest scope possible and for the most specific type possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should put that Int32.Parse() call inside the try-catch. In fact, that method will throw an exception of that type in case the argument is not parsable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use TryParse. It returns true, when the parsing worked, and false otherwise:

```
string myLine = Console.ReadLine();
int IloscPracownikow = 0;
if(!Int32.TryParse(myLine, out IloscPracownikow))
{
       Console.WriteLine("Podaj liczbe, debilu");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Catch` will only be executed if it has an exception within the `try block`, as its variable declaration is out of scope it will not catch the exception.