# C# - how to catch input exception and continue program to run - BMI calculator

Tags: c#, validation, exception, input, try-catch

I have a BMI calculator code, however I need to handle exceptions somehow. By exception I mean different input format than expected (example - user is asked to input his weight in kg and he puts letters instead). In this case program should throw error msg "Please give correct weight in kg" and continue to run (ask about height, throw exception if height is not correct, calculate bmi, etc.) How to handle using try catch or parse?
How to define variables in such cases?

```
namespace BMI
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Console.Write("Give your weight in kg: ");
        double weight= Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Give your height in m: ");
        double height= Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        double BMI = (weight/ (height * height));
        Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + Math.Round(BMI, 2));

        if (BMI < 16)
            Console.WriteLine("text");
        else
            if (BMI < 18.5)
            Console.WriteLine("text text");
        else
            if (BMI < 25)
            Console.WriteLine("text text text");
        else
            if (BMI > 25)
            Console.WriteLine("text text text");

        Console.ReadKey();
    
    }  
        
        
 }
```

}

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?  You already have the terminology you're looking for: try, catch, exception.  When you look up how to do that in C# and make an attempt, what happens?  As an aside, you don't *need* to handle the exception if you check the input before trying to convert it.  Take a look at `double.TryParse` for that.

Comment: Exceptions are for things you don't expect, like out of memory, or HTTP connection broken.   User input being in the wrong format is not unexpected.  As @David points out, it's better to use double.TryParse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Try-catch FormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488288/try-catch-formatexception)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be `double.TryParse()`. This returns a boolean if the string is able to be parsed into a double variable.

Here is a example of how you do it:

```
double outputVariable;
if(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out outputVariable))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Input is unable to be parsed");
}
else
    Console.WriteLine($"The output {outputVariable} is a double");
}
```